# La fecha de mi componente React no se actualiza

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

La idea del componente funcional es que cada un segundo se actualice la 'fecha' y la 'edad', la edad se actualiza bien, pero no consigo que la fecha se actualice.

```
const ClockFunction = () => {
  const defaultState = {
    fecha: new Date(),
    edad: 0,
    nombre: "Juan",
    apellidos: "Martinez",
  };

  const updateUser = () => {
    return setUser({
        fecha: user.fecha,
        edad: user.edad + 1,
        nombre: user.nombre,
        apellidos: user.apellidos,
    });
  };

  const [user, setUser] = useState(defaultState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalAge = setInterval(() => {
        updateUser();
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
        clearInterval(intervalAge);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
        <h2>
            Hora Actual:
            {user.fecha.toLocaleTimeString()}
        </h2>
        <h3>
            {user.nombre} {user.apellidos}
        </h3>
        <h1>Edad: {user.edad}</h1>
    </div>
  );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando estableces que el estado sea `defaultState`, estás estableciendo un valor estático  de `new Date()` a la propiedad `fecha`, donde tomará el valor del momento en que se llamó (o sea, en el `useState`). En el interval, solo estás llamando al `updateUser` y, por ende, reemplazas los mismos valores estáticos al estado (menos `edad` que le sumas 1).
Puedes obtener lo que buscas y minimizar líneas de código usando dentro de `useEffect` el `setUser` en su versión de arrow function junto al `spread operator` ya que buscas setear el nuevo estado usando el estado anterior. (En la [doc oficial](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) de React se encuentra esto). Tu `useEffect` quedaría así:

```
const ClockFunction = () => {
  const defaultState = {
    fecha: new Date(),
    edad: 0,
    nombre: 'Juan',
    apellidos: 'Martinez',
  }
  const [user, setUser] = useState(defaultState)

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalAge = setInterval(() => {
      setUser((curr) => ({
        ...curr,
        edad: curr.edad + 1,
        fecha: new Date(),
      }))
    }, 1000)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalAge)
    }
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>
        Hora Actual:
        {user.fecha.toLocaleTimeString()}
      </h2>
      <h3>
        {user.nombre} {user.apellidos}
      </h3>
      <h4>Edad: {user.edad}</h4>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Ya esta editado :)

Comment: ya está respondido :D